# Drop Cap and P tag not respected on description

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code in my event_single.php in tribe_events folder under theme. I've been trying to do the drop cap but it seems that this is not working and even the p tag is not being respected.

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('event__main'); ?>>
    <?php while (have_posts()):  the_post(); ?>
        <div class="event__description page__content">
            <h3 class="event__description__title"><?php _e('Description') ?></h3>
            <?php do_action('tribe_events_single_event_before_the_content') ?>
            <?php
                $content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());
                echo preg_replace('/<p>(.)/', '<p><span class="drop-cap">$1</span>', $content, 1);
            ?>
            <?php do_action('tribe_events_single_event_after_the_content') ?>
        </div>

        <div class="event__details">
            <?php do_action('tribe_events_single_event_before_the_meta') ?>
            <?php tribe_get_template_part('modules/meta'); ?>
            <?php do_action('tribe_events_single_event_after_the_meta') ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```